# Multiplicar los datos de dos columnas diferentes y que el resultado se agregue en otra columna

Tags: php, base-de-datos, phpmyadmin

tengo ese pequeño problemita, quiero que se multipliquen los datos de dos columnas diferentes y que el resultado se agregue en otra columna.

Es de una página que me registra la venta de unos accesorios, utilizo diferentes php, uno para agregar la venta (ventas_agregar), otro para que me muestre el listado de las ventas (ventas_listado), otro para buscar un articulo en especifico (ventas_buscar).

Los datos que se registran (las columnas que tengo tanto en mi tabla como en PhpMyAdmin) son producto (nombre del producto), precio, cantidad, *subtotal* , fecha de registro y fecha de compra. Lo que quiero hacer, como lo comenté arriba es que se multipliquen los valores de las columnas *precio* y *cantidad*, y que el resultado se vaya a la nueva columna de *subtotal*.

También un compañero me dijo que lo podia hacer directo desde el ventas_agregar.php, supongo que para que desde un inicio se agregara el subtotal, pero pues tampoco se bien como hacerlo. A parte quisiera que las ventas anteriores también se modificaran agregando el subtotal, no se si me explique.

Les adjunto los códigos de php que tengo

(ventas_agregar)

```html
<?php

  $xnombre = $_REQUEST['Nombre_Apellido'];
  $xproducto = $_REQUEST['Producto'];
  $xprecio = $_REQUEST['Precio'];
  $xcantidad= $_REQUEST['Cantidad'];
  $xtelefono = $_REQUEST['Telefono'];  
  $xcorreo = $_REQUEST ['Correo'];
  $xfecha = $_REQUEST ['Fecha'];
  

  echo "FELICIDADES, TU VENTA HA SIDO REGISTRADA!";
  
  echo "<br>";
  
  echo "<br>";
  echo "Nombre : ".$xnombre;
  echo "<br>";
  echo "<br>";
  echo "Producto : ".$xproducto;
  echo "<br>";
  echo "<br>";
  echo "Precio : ".$xprecio;
  echo "<br>";
  echo "<br>";
  echo "Cantidad: ".$xcantidad;
  echo "<br>";
  echo "<br>";
  echo "Telefono : ".$xtelefono;
  echo "<br>";
  echo "<br>";
  echo "Correo : ".$xcorreo; 
  echo "<br>";
    echo "<br>";
   echo "Fecha : ".$xfecha; 
  echo "<br>";
  
   $link = mysqli_connect('localhost', ':D', ':d') or die('No se pudo conectar con el Servidor: ' . mysqli_error()); 
  mysqli_select_db($link,'sis_datos') or die('No se pudo seleccionar con la base de datos');
  
  $query = "insert into alejandro_ventas (Nombre_Apellido,Producto,Precio,Cantidad,Subutotal,Telefono,Correo,Fecha) 
   values ('".$xnombre."','".$xproducto."','".$xprecio."','".$xcantidad."','".$xsubtotal."','".$xtelefono."','".$xcorreo."','".$xfecha."')";

  $result = mysqli_query($link,$query);
```

(ventas_listado)

```html
<body>  
<div align='center'>  
  <table  border='2' cellpadding='2' cellspacing='1' width='1500' bgcolor='b781b3' bordercolor='581461'>  
    <tr>  
      <td width='10' text align= 'center' style='font-weight: bold'>ID</td>
      <td width='20' text align= 'center'  style='font-weight: bold'>NOMBRE</td>
      <td width='20' text align= 'center'  style='font-weight: bold'>PRODUCTO</td>
      <td width='20' text align= 'center'  style='font-weight: bold'>PRECIO</td>
      <td width='20' text align= 'center'  style='font-weight: bold'>CANTIDAD</td>
      <td width='20' text align= 'center'  style='font-weight: bold'>SUBTOTAL</td>
      <td width='20' text align= 'center'  style='font-weight: bold'>TELÉFONO</td>
      <td width='50' text align= 'center'  style='font-weight: bold'>CORREO</td>
      <td width='20' text align= 'center'  style='font-weight: bold'>FECHA DE REGISTRO</td>
      <td width='20' text align= 'center'  style='font-weight: bold'>FECHA DE VENTA</td>

    </tr>  



<?php  


    $link = mysqli_connect('localhost', ':D', ':d') or die('No se pudo conectar a Servidor: ' . mysqli_error()); 
    mysqli_select_db($link,'sis_datos') or die('No se pudo seleccionar la base de datos');


    
    $query = "select * from alejandro_ventas order by IDCliente asc";     


    $result = mysqli_query($link,$query);
    $tot_registros = 0;
    while ($registro = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){  
     
    
      
      echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td>".$registro['IDCliente'].   "</td>";
      echo "<td>".$registro['Nombre_Apellido']."</td>";
      echo "<td>".$registro['Producto']."</td>";
      echo "<td>".$registro['Precio']."</td>";
      echo "<td>".$registro['Cantidad']."</td>";
      echo "<td>".$registro['Subtotal']."</td>";
      echo "<td>".$registro['Telefono']."</td>";
      echo "<td>".$registro['Correo']."</td>";
      echo "<td>".$registro['Hora y Fecha'].   "</td>";
      echo "<td>".$registro['Fecha'].   "</td>";
      echo "</tr>";
      
  }  
?>  
   </table>  
</div>  
</body>  

</html>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Todo lo que tiene que ver con **subtotal** lo agregué despues, pero no se si esta bien

Comment: Por favor, adjunta tu código para poder ayudarte mejor

Comment: Para preguntas de bases de datos, sólo tendrás una respuesta que te sirva si incluyes la definición de las tablas, datos de prueba, la consulta que estás intentando usar y la salida esperada. Todo como texto, no como imagen (que replicar errores desde una imagen es harto difícil). Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el funcionamiento y ya de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
Por otro lado, podrías echar un vistazo a [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tus preguntas reciban respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Ya edité la pregunta, gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supongo que lo que quieres es hacer un `update` de la/s fila/s de la tabla venta. La siguiente sentencia actualiza la columna subtotal de toda la tabla, añade un where con los datos que quieres actualizar.

```
UPDATE venta 
SET Subtotal = Cantidad * b.Precio
FROM venta a
INNER JOIN productos b on a.id_producto = b.id_producto
```

Si es para una línea de venta concreta, anañdes un `where`con el identificador de la línea de venta.

Comment: Hola. Podría sugerirte revisar [este hilo](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4124/por-qu%c3%a9-no-existe-penalizaci%c3%b3n-a-quien-le-haga-la-tarea-a-un-usuario-nuevo/4142#4142) en meta? No dudo de tu amabilidad al responder estas preguntas, pero considero que sería valioso si buscamos que quienes preguntan demuestren esfuerzo por trabajar en el problema y en plantear una pregunta que le sirva a otros en el futuro. :)